# Past Tense using Time expression with Have and Had

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

Which one is correct statement?

1. Last year also I have not received any increment, or
2. Last year also I had not received any increment

Both statements are suggesting that one has not received any increment last year. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

My questions are:

1. Which sentence is correct?
2. Is the time expression *"Last Year"* correct to use in the sentences?
3. *"Had"* is used to suggest past of Past. But the second sentence does not suggest that what has happen after he had not received increment?

   ```
   E.g. 2013__I have not received increment___2014 (Till the time)______________
        2013__I had not received increment___(Second Past?)___2014 (Till the time)_________
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say that you haven't received any increment since last year, you can change the sentence 'a' as **"I haven't received any increment since last year."**.

If you simply want to imply that you didn't receive any increment this year as well as last year, you can use **"(I didn't receive any increment this year.) Last year also, I hadn't received any increment."**.

Time expression "Last year" is correct.

Comment: The simplest of all for last year is "I didn't receive an increment last year, either". We don't need a past perfect.